# BootstrapVue Styling of b-list-group and b-list-group-item

Tags: css, bootstrap-vue

So, I am having a rough time trying to style a navbar with social media icons in it. I am trying to achieve something similar to: https://codepen.io/matthew-spire/pen/GVQvJg, but I have no clue how to even go about it.

Right now I just have:

```
<!-- Social Media Navigation -->
    <b-navbar type="dark" variant="dark" class="justify-content-center">
      <b-list-group horizontal>
        <b-list-group-item href="#" target="_blank"><font-awesome :icon="['fab', 'instagram']" size="2x"/></b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item href="#" target="_blank"><font-awesome :icon="['fab', 'facebook-f']" size="2x"/></b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item href="#" target="_blank"><font-awesome :icon="['fab', 'twitter']" size="2x"/></b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item href="#" target="_blank"><font-awesome :icon="['fab', 'youtube']" size="2x"/></b-list-group-item>
      </b-list-group>
    </b-navbar>
```

Any suggestions or places to look? I have already tinkered around and tried to access what I want and style it accordingly, but with nowhere near the results I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution that I had a lot of help on. Way more work than I expected.

The HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="dark" variant="dark" class="justify-content-center">

    <!-- Right aligned nav items -->
    <b-navbar-nav>
      <div class="instagram-circle circle text-center">
        <b-link class="social-icon" href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></b-link>
      </div>

      <div class="facebook-circle circle text-center">
        <b-link class="social-icon" href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-lg"></i></b-link>
      </div>

      <div class="twitter-circle circle text-center">
        <b-link class="social-icon" href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></b-link>
      </div>

      <div class="youtube-circle circle text-center">
        <b-link class="social-icon" href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-lg"></i></b-link>
      </div>

    </b-navbar-nav>
  </b-navbar>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.social-icon {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.social-icon:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.facebook-circle:hover {
  background: #4060a5;
}

.twitter-circle:hover {
  background: #00abe3;
}

.instagram-circle:hover {
  background: #375989;
}

.youtube-circle:hover {
  background: #ff1f25 !important;
}

.circle {
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

The JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {};
  }
});
```

A link to codepen: https://codepen.io/matthew-spire/pen/mNxbyR

Answer (score 0):

Use the `b-navbar-nav` and `b-nav-item` components (instead of the `b-list-group`, which is not a supported child component of a navbar) to generate the social icon links, and then use Vue-loader's deep selector to style the icons as needed.

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements